# File_put_contents and DOM not fetching url feed to a file - Port blocked

Tags: php, save, fetch, file-get-contents, feed

I have a dev and a prod environment. Fetching the url feed content works on my dev(local vps), but it's not on my prod server(shared). I don't know what can be the issue.

The feed is a product list which gets imported into magento. It's pretty heavy on size 1.3MB. It's being saved on the server for processing.

But on the shared server it does not return any error just fails to save the file. I've tried with the DOM and the file_put_contents() function as well.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
        try{

            $xml = file_get_contents($url);
        } catch(Exception $e){
            echo "<br>Error fetching the feed contents: ".$e;
        }

        $good_xml = iconv("utf-8", "utf-8//ignore", $xml);




        if ($good_xml != $xml) {
            echo "The feed contains invalid characters";
        }

        try {
            file_put_contents('feed.xml', $good_xml);
        }catch (Exception $e){

            echo "<br>Error fetching the feed contents: ".$e;
        }
```

Here's the implemented situation.

[Dev Server](http://dev.imok.ro/ski/connect/stock)

[Prod Server](http://www.ski-shop.ro/connect/stock)

Any suggestion helps! 
Thanks!

Istvan

Comment: Which part is failing, `file_get_contents` or `file_put_contents`?

Comment: Please, try to copy contents in a local file in your prod server, and after that, execute de `file_get_contents('file.xml')`, if this test works, then the possible problem is that you can't get contents form dev server. This could  bring to us an scenario more clear about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses :)

I figured out the issue.. it was a blocked port. On the prod server the port 8000 had to be enabled after that it was spotless.

Cheers!